# OpenShift: Cannot Connect to WebSocket with Alias (bug)

Tags: websocket, openshift, spring-websocket, openshift-origin, java-websocket

I have a ***Java Spring Web application*** which uses WebSockets. An HTML file connects to the WebSocket using the uri:

```
var wsUri = "wss://" + document.location.hostname + ":8443" + "/serverendpoint";
```

Here is my serverendpoint.java code that creates the WebSocket:

```
package com.myapp.spring.web.controller;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.SpringConfigurator;


@ServerEndpoint(value="/serverendpoint", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)

public class serverendpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen () {
        System.out.println("JAVA: Client is now connected...");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage (Session session, String message) throws IOException {

        if (message.equals("ping")) {
//            return "pong"
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText("pong");
        }
        else if (message.equals("close")) {
            handleClose();
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("JAVA: Received from client: "+ message);
        MyClass mc = new MyClass(message);
        String res = mc.action();
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(res);
        return res;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void handleClose() {
        System.out.println("JAVA: Client is now disconnected...");
    }

    @OnError
    public void handleError (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I connect to the websocket using the http://myapp-myproject.rhcloud.com/mt URL, the WebSocket connects. However, when I set up an alias to the http://myapp-myproject.rhcloud.com, which is called https://someurl.com/mt, the websocket doesn't connect. Why is this? I get the following error message in Google Chrome:
[image]

Furthermore, the websocket uses a wss connection at port 8443. This is a secure request equivalent to https. Therefore, how can it work with the http://myapp-myproject.rhcloud.com/mt URL which is an http URL, and why is it not connecting with the alias?

Thank you so much for your help!